# Can I define a static constexpr data member only for certain specializations?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr, one-definition-rule

The following program works just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename DummyT = void>
struct wrapper
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<void, DummyT>::value, "Only void, please");
  static constexpr char text[] = "some string constant";
};

template <typename DummyT>
constexpr char wrapper<DummyT>::text[];

int
main()
{
  std::cout << wrapper<>::text << '\n';
}
```

However, when I only define `wrapper::text` for `wrapper<void>`,

```
template <>
constexpr char wrapper<void>::text[];
```

then GCC 5.3.0 gives me this linker error

```
/tmp/ccnGx3EP.o: In function `main':
main.cxx:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `wrapper<void>::text'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and Clang 3.7.1 gives me this error.

```
main.cxx:12:31: error: declaration of constexpr static data member 'text' requires an initializer
constexpr char wrapper<void>::text[];
                              ^
1 error generated.
```

I'm wondering why it isn't sufficient to provide a definition only for the specialization that is actually used. Not that it would be terribly useful as a `static` `constexpr` member has to be initialized inside the `class` definition so I cannot specialize it in the definition anyway but I might want to leave it undefined.

Comment: An explicit specialization effectively replaces the declaration/definition in the primary template.

Comment: @T.C. i was in the assumption that the in-class initialization of a static data member is not a definition. So shouldn't the declaration+initialization in the template body apply to all specilizations-for-implicit-instantiations-of-class-template of the data member?

Comment: @T.C. yes, my gut-feeling was right: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/597464c14d48071f . So, his problem is that he can't provide a defining specialization without also providing an initializer, since the latter only declares the specialization. But if he does the latter, he will have two initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Easily:

```
template <typename DummyT = void>
struct wrapper
{
  static_assert(std::is_same<void, DummyT>::value, "Only void, please");
};

template <>
struct wrapper<void>
{
  static constexpr char text[] = "some string constant";
};

constexpr char wrapper<void>::text[];
```

Both `wrapper<>` and `wrapper<void>` will work while any other parameter will fail with a `static_assert`.

Comment: While this is a nice trick I didn't think of, unfortunately, it will cause a multiple definition error when `#include`d into more than one translation unit and linked together, thus reducing ad absurdum the purpose of using a `template` in the first place.

Comment: The multiple definition problem goes away if the line "constexpr char wrapper<void>::text[];" is moved into a cpp (rather than header) file. This can be any cpp file used in the compilation, including possibly into its own cpp file containing only 2 code lines (an #include statement plus the definition itself) - I have personally used the latter approach many times when needing to provide a static member definition for a template class.